# Capacitor Geolocation gradle build errors in android studio

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am unable to use @capacitor/geolocation as the build keeps on failing

The versions that I have currently are

```
"@capacitor/core": "^4.6.3"

"@capacitor/geolocation": "^4.1.0"
```

[image: Image of android studio]

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I'm having a similar issue with the same versions.